# python script to compare 2 files by ignoring timestamp

Tags: python

I have two log files: `log A` and `log B`. Their contents are something like :

**log A**

```
2014-07-12 09:50:33,904 dk,jnbxkmgl,mb.;/lkngjn.....

2014-07-12 09:56:45,060 ;lkjdgzkblnx.m.mc;xgjjjjjj....

2014-07-12 10:00:00,001 uzlk>FFhkshfGBKNMlaL>Djgdkgh....
```

**log B**

```
2015-06-12 08:50:33,904 gk;s'ahdsjgkagZCXseiutr....

2015-08-12 07:56:45,060 pisazffksikfdjggdkjhfg...

2015-09-12 10:00:00,001 ffffsajggjaaaaaa.....
```

I want to compare the two log files but by ignoring their timestamp i.e. first 20 characters of both files. I am new to Python so not sure how to write a Python script that can compare these two files by ignoring timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

If the time stamp always has the same format - e. g. always 20 chars long, you could ignore and compare them by using `lineA[20:]` and `lineB[20:]`.

To get the diff of two strings you can use difflib for python. The following code was taken from [this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904097/python-difference-between-two-strings)

```
import difflib

cases=[('afrykanerskojęzyczny', 'afrykanerskojęzycznym'),
       ('afrykanerskojęzyczni', 'nieafrykanerskojęzyczni'),
       ('afrykanerskojęzycznym', 'afrykanerskojęzyczny'),
       ('nieafrykanerskojęzyczni', 'afrykanerskojęzyczni'),
       ('nieafrynerskojęzyczni', 'afrykanerskojzyczni'),
       ('abcdefg','xac')] 

for a,b in cases:     
    print('{} => {}'.format(a,b))  
    for i,s in enumerate(difflib.ndiff(a, b)):
        if s[0]==' ': continue
        elif s[0]=='-':
            print(u'Delete "{}" from position {}'.format(s[-1],i))
        elif s[0]=='+':
            print(u'Add "{}" to position {}'.format(s[-1],i))    
    print()
```